# How do I verify if it is a positive value string?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

The function returns `true` if it is a string representing a positive number, so for example:

- "1" is true
- "One" is false
- "-3" is false
- "3.1.2" is false

Comment: Can you tell me why false for 3.1.2 please?

Comment: The function in the question already states it as a false input

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match the string. For example this regex pattern should match all positive integers (I have taken the regex rules from java Pattern class):

```
((\+)[0-9]+)|([0-9]+)
```

`((\+)[0-9]+)` matches strings of type +329, +943 ...
`([0-9]+)` matches strings of type 1,2, 23 ...